# $index in ng-click works in firefox not in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following in my view

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.getItems() track by $index" class="cart-item">
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
        <td><price value="item.price"></td>
        <td><button ng-click="remove(cart.getItems(), $index)">remove</button></td>
 </tr>
```

where the `remove()` function is defined as follows:

```
$scope.remove = function(array, index){
    array.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Interestingly it works fine in firefox 31.8.0 but not in  Google Chrome 44.0.2403.89 beta (64-bit) where clicking on the `remove` button does not remove items. What's the problem?

Comment: What does `cart.getItems()` look like?

Comment: showing any console error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not use methods in ng-repeat. Assign data to some scope model, like `$scope.cartItems` and repeat it.

Second, in remove method, pass only current item: `<button ng-click="remove(item)">`

Third, in controller:

```
$scope.remove = function(item){
    var index = $scope.cartItems.indexOf(item);
    $scope.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible needs a `$scope.$apply()` right after your `array.splice()` to force the re-binding.

Alternatively, rather than calling `.getItems()` twice in your view and passing that back to the controller, just set the array in your controller scope and reference it in your view and also your remove method.

So in your controller:

`$scope.cartItems = cart.getItems();`

Then your view would be:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in cartItems track by $index" class="cart-item">
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
        <td><price value="item.price"></td>
        <td><button ng-click="remove($index)">remove</button></td>
 </tr>
```

and your remove method:

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
    $scope.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Then you're keeping everything references nicely within angular